# How do I modify custom radius for each corner of a rectangle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014

I'm new to Illustrator and now I want to create a rounded rectangle with `10px 0px 10px 0px` radius for corner, how can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This only works in Illustrator CC or newer.**

1. Draw a rectangle
2. Use the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd> (White Arrow on Toolbar)
3. Pick one corner
4. Use the little circle that appears to create a radius

[image]

[image]

You can double click the circle to enter exact figures:

[image]

Comment: when i click the corner, no circle appears

Comment: @user28130 are you sure you have version CC? Here is a video showing how to do this: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-live-corners.html#modify_corner_types_and_edit_corners_individually_

Comment: I don't think this works in Illustrator 2022 anymore

Answer (score 5):

**In CS6 and earlier:**

There is no dynamic way to do this as far as I know. The easiest way to do what you want is to use the **rectangle tool**, and shape it to the size you want.

Then go to

```
Appearance Window > Stylize > Rounded Corners > 10px
```

and then hit

```
Object > Expand Appearance
```

and zoom into the top right corners and adjust the nodes so that the corner ends up square and repeat with the other one.

Comment: In newer versions they created a dynamic way. If you're using Illustrator CS6 or earlier than you'd be correct that there isn't.

Comment: for earlier versions I would recommend the "Round any corner" script: http://theitbros.com/adobe-illustrator-cs6-round-one-corner/ where you can select as many corners as you want and round them independently.

Answer (score 0):

In CC 2018, you must first select- with the direct select tool or lasso- *only the point or points associated with the the corner you want to work with*. Then you can use the widget to adjust that corner's radius independently. Note that with an already rounded corner there are 2 associated points. The good news is that any corner in any shape can be adjusted now.