# I would like to recreate this specific paragraph style in this picture but I am not sure how

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, formatting

[image: Example of paragraph style effect]

I am trying to recreate this style with the shading, curved end, etc. I want to find a efficient way to create these titles in a repeating fashion.

In fact every one of my titles need to be like this. So I figured I would do a paragraph style, but it doesn't seem to be advanced enough to create this kind of style...

Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im hestiant about showing you how to do this because you still haven't show any effort but Im having a great day so Im going to pass along the love.  This is how I would do it:

- Create the shape in Illustrator and round the corner (reference: [How do I modify custom radius for each corner of a rectangle in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/how-do-i-modify-custom-radius-for-each-corner-of-a-rectangle-in-illustrator)):

[image]

- Export shape as an EPS file and import into InDesign:

[image]

- Create your text and give it a paragraph style and place it over your EPS file:

[image]

-If you select the text it should highlight your paragraph style:

[image]

- Select your EPS file and text and center them and then group:

[image]

- In the top right you will see a solid square, if you leave the cursor there is will tell you drag and drop:

[image]

- Drag that into where it is to go with the text:

[image]

Now the solid square will turn into an anchor.

Sometimes when you anchor it can cause issues with the text.  To modify this you can right click on the anchor and go to anchored options:

[image]

[image]

That should be what you need.  If you need anything else please make an edit to your question.

Comment: I love you. @darth_vader